# Remote keyboard and mouse - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, remote-access, remote-control

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Remote control Linux keyboard/mouse](https://superuser.com/questions/281262/remote-control-linux-keyboard-mouse)
>   [Remote control a computer using another computer](https://superuser.com/questions/85884/remote-control-a-computer-using-another-computer)

I have my TV connected to a computer which I can start remotely via ethernet from another computer. I would love to use my laptop as a remote for the keyboard and mouse to browse my movie library on that computer etc.

Is there a software I can install on that media computer and on my laptop to control the keyboard and mouse? With VNC I also have the video which I don't want. I would want to just switch seamlessly.

Comment: @sblair: the tag says windows-7, so it's not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: @alex Yes, but I think it's close enough of a duplicate to be closed, because the answer is almost certainly the same in each case. If not, then how about [this](http://superuser.com/questions/79322/remote-screen-control) or [this](http://superuser.com/questions/85884/remote-control-a-computer-using-another-computer)?

Comment: @sblair good point, voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org) is what you're looking for.

Comment: You voted to close _and_ answered? [Some](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/787/high-reputation-users-having-trouble-understanding-super-user/789#789) [people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43385/should-there-be-a-reputation-cost-for-duplicate-questions) [frown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/should-you-gain-rep-for-asking-a-duplicate-question) [upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82420/remove-rep-gained-from-answering-a-question-that-is-a-duplicate) [that](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).

Comment: Although, I'm not sure it's necessarily bad, given the arguments in the latter parts of: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/. Should this be meta'd?

Comment: If an answer is a duplicate I like to give a very short answer and point to the duplicate.  If the OP requires more detail they can read the duplicate.